# 16.04 horrible battery life all of a sudden

Tags: 16.04, dell, power-management, battery

I've been using ubuntu for the last month or so on my laptop and it's been working fine, up until last week. I am using a Dell XPS 15 9570

Nothing has changed except I followed this guide https://medium.com/@maxmckinney/impr...u-b4ff6fb5cf1a to fix palm rejection. I AM NOT SURE IF THIS IS RELATED

Ever since then, any time i open my laptop after closing it it works for about a minute, then freezes for about a minute, and then continues working normally.
The battery life has also been horrendous, I used to get ~11 hours, now I get ~6.

This is the output of running `powertop`- https://pastebin.com/nkuYMaqE

As you can see it's using a lot of power. My battery was at 87% at that moment in time.

I've since reverted the fix for palm rejection, and still having all these issues - so not sure if it's related or not.
I'd appreciate any help, I'm considering doing a fresh install of Ubuntu but I'd like to avoid this if possible since I have everything already configured to my liking.

Thanks

Comment: It might be worth looking to see if there are new battery drivers for your device. It's a long shot but there is little harm in trying. Also, you may be able to get some information out of the "power statistics" program. It may be that the computer has updated it's guess of how much battery life is left based on the health of your battery.